# Drupal views caching incorrect pager URLs

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-views

I have a few web-pages that have incorrect URL patterns in the pager generated from a view.

http://www.csun.edu/family-focus-resource-center
[image]

You may need to click on one or two pager elements to see the problem kick in. The URL for page 2 should be http://www.csun.edu/family-focus-resource-center?page=1 but instead you will see some semi random elements in the URL such as http://www.csun.edu/family-focus-resource-center/category/ffrc-events?page=1&month=2015-12

This will change every so often (I believe every 30 minutes). The view caches the query and the html for 30 minutes.

Our site is hosted which we have our domain in our DNS point to the real host.  We cannot recreate the issue on the real host http://csunorth.prod.acquia-sites.com/family-focus-resource-center
[image]

We also cannot recreate the issue on test or staging which both have their own host that points to the real host.

How can I resolve this?

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide that may help find a solution.